# Some issues in positioning arrows and labeling them

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning

I want to draw something like this. 
[image]

But I am able draw this things:

[image]

So there are three problems:

1. Input and output arrows not positioned properly.
2. I want a rectangle above 5 X 1 MUX text.
3. I am not able to position text properly inside a block. Like I want x in    front of every arrow.

I am attaching my tex code

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick]

\node [input, name=input] {};
\node [block, right of=input,minimum width=3cm, minimum height=2.5cm,node distance=0.5cm] (a) {Frame Encoder};
\node [block, right of=a,minimum width=3cm, minimum height=5cm,node distance=5cm] (b) {};
\node [block, right of=b, pin={[pinstyle]above:Ack},minimum width=3cm, minimum height=5cm,node distance=5cm] (c) {$5$ $\times$ $1$ MUX};
\node [output,right of=c] (output) {};

\begin{scope}[->,>=latex]

\draw[->] (input) -- (a);
\draw[->] (c) -- (output);
\foreach \i in {-2,...,2}{% 
  \draw[->] ([yshift=\i * 0.4 cm]a.east) -- ([yshift=\i * 0.8 cm]b.west) ;}

\foreach \i in {-2,...,2}{% 
  \draw[->] ([yshift=\i * 0.8 cm]b.east) -- ([yshift=\i * 0.8 cm]c.west) ;}

\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Thanks a lot for the help. My most of the problems got resolved. There is only one problem now. I want this x's to be numbered. For that, I am using count as some suggested. But now it doesn't compile. What mistake am I making?

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick]
\tikzset{input/.style={}}     
\tikzset{block/.style={rectangle,draw}}
\tikzstyle{pinstyle} = [pin edge={to-,thick,black}]

\node [input, name=input] {};
\node [block, right=1cm of input,minimum width=3cm, minimum height=2.5cm] (a) {Frame Encoder};
\node [block, right of=a,minimum width=3cm, minimum height=5cm,node distance=5cm] (b) {};
\node [block, right of=b, pin={[pinstyle]above:Ack},minimum width=3cm, minimum height=5cm,node distance=5cm] (c) {$5$ $\times$ $1$ MUX};
\node [right =1cm of c] (output) {};

\begin{scope}[->,>=latex]

\draw[->] (input) -- (a);

\node at (b.center) {\footnotesize{z}};

\draw[above] ($(c.text)+(0,1)$)rectangle ($(c.text)+(1.85,2)$);

\draw[->] (c) -- (output);

\foreach \i [count=\xi]in {2,...,-2}{% 
\draw[->] ([yshift=\i * 0.4 cm]a.east) -- ([yshift=\i * 0.8 cm]b.west) node[right]{\footnotesize{$x_{\xi}$}} ;}

\foreach \i in {-2,...,2}{% 
\draw[->] ([yshift=\i * 0.8 cm]b.east) -- ([yshift=\i * 0.8 cm]c.west) ;}

\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it. This is especially true with `tikz` as there are numerous packages.

Comment: you can remove -> in the last scope for all the commands `\draw` it's an option of the scope ! and you can add some graphic parameters in the style  `block`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) Input and output arrows not positioned properly :

It's normal here because by default `right of=input` places a node at 1 cm to the right of (input) but the width of your new node given by  `minimum width=3cm` is 3 cm. (input) is inside the new node. You make the same mistake for (output).
You can use the library positioning with right=3cm of input or you can use 'anchor=west`.

2)  You get a rectangle with the use of `(c.center)` and a `yshift`

3) For the text, the question is unclear

Here a solution if the picture needs a scale action

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
 %\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning} no it's not useful
\begin{document} 


\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,scale=.8]
\tikzset{input/.style={}} % <= this can be avoided but then use simply \node[name=input]{};
\tikzset{block/.style={rectangle,fill=blue!15,draw,anchor=west,minimum width=3cm,minimum height=5cm}} % to avoid some repetitions
\node [input, name=input] {};
\node [block, minimum height=2.5cm] (a) at ([xshift=1cm]input) {Frame Encoder};
\node [block ] (b) at ([xshift=4cm]a) {};
\node [block, right of=b, pin={above:Ack}] (c) at ([xshift=4cm]b) {$5$ $\times$ $1$ MUX};
\node  (output) at ([xshift=3cm]c)  {};  
\node [draw,minimum height =1cm,minimum width=1.85cm,below=.5cm] at (c.north)  {};
\node at (b.center) {\footnotesize{z}};

\begin{scope}[->,>=latex]
\draw (input) -- (a); % I remove  -> because it's an option of the scope !
\draw (c) -- (output); % idem

\foreach \i [count=\xi] in {-2,...,2}{% remove  ->
  \draw ([yshift=\i * 0.4 cm]a.east) -- ([yshift=\i * 0.8 cm]b.west)  
             node[right]{\footnotesize{$x_\xi$}} ;}

\foreach \i in {-2,...,2}{% remove  ->
  \draw ([yshift=\i * 0.8 cm]b.east) -- ([yshift=\i * 0.8 cm]c.west) ;}

\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: One small doubt : How do I write x_1, x_2, ..., x_5 instead of x?

Comment: I modify my answer for your request. I used `[count=\xi]`

Answer (score 3):

My solution leads to:

[image]

The `pinstyle`, as all others styles are not given in your question so I declared just important ones.

The code is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick]
\tikzset{input/.style={}} % <= this can be avoided but then use simply \node[name=input]{};
\tikzset{block/.style={rectangle,fill=blue!15,draw}}
\node [input, name=input] {};
\node [block, right=1cm of input,minimum width=3cm, minimum height=2.5cm] (a) {Frame Encoder};
\node [block, right of=a,minimum width=3cm, minimum height=5cm,node distance=5cm] (b) {};
\node [block, right of=b, pin={[]above:Ack},minimum width=3cm, minimum height=5cm,node distance=5cm] (c) {$5$ $\times$ $1$ MUX};
\node [right =1cm of c] (output) {};

\begin{scope}[->,>=latex]

\draw[->] (input) -- (a);

% text in the center of the block b
\node at (b.center) {\footnotesize{z}};

% a rectangle in the c block
\draw[above] ($(c.text)+(0,1)$)rectangle ($(c.text)+(1.85,2)$);

\draw[->] (c) -- (output);
\foreach \i in {-2,...,2}{% 
  \draw[->] ([yshift=\i * 0.4 cm]a.east) -- ([yshift=\i * 0.8 cm]b.west) node[right]{\footnotesize{x}} ;} %<= this to place x in front of each arrow

\foreach \i in {-2,...,2}{% 
  \draw[->] ([yshift=\i * 0.8 cm]b.east) -- ([yshift=\i * 0.8 cm]c.west) ;}

\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

> **Explanation**

- For `input` and `output` you can avoid to declare a style that actually is empty (in the code you will find a comment on that).
- To place a `z` exactly in the center of a block you can use simply:

  `\node at (b.center) {\footnotesize{z}};`

  for all keys available please refer to the pgfmanual 48.2 Predefined Shapes - rectangle.
- To insert `x` in front of each arrow, it is possible to place a node with the text after the `\draw` in your `foreach`.
- Finally, to place the rectangle above the text, I prefer using the `calc` library rather than `yshift` as Altermundus suggested. Moreover I started from `c.text` instead of `c.center`.

> **EDIT**

To insert numbered `x`, change the `\foreach` into:

```
\draw[->] (c) -- (output);
\foreach \i [count=\xi]in {2,...,-2}{% 
  \draw[->] ([yshift=\i * 0.4 cm]a.east) -- ([yshift=\i * 0.8 cm]b.west) node[right]{\footnotesize{$x_{\xi}$}} ;}
```

to have numbers that starts from the top or:

```
\draw[->] (c) -- (output);
\foreach \i [count=\xi]in {-2,...,2}{% 
  \draw[->] ([yshift=\i * 0.4 cm]a.east) -- ([yshift=\i * 0.8 cm]b.west) node[right]{\footnotesize{$x_{\xi}$}} ;}
```

from the bottom. The first solution gives:

[image]

Comment: I prefer `c.center` or `c.north` because it's a central point. `c.center` is interesting only if the dimensions of the rectangle depends of the text but in this case you need to use the width of the text. Then I think it's preferable to use a node to draw the rectangle. It's more coherent because all the shapes come from nodes. Then with `right= of` is a problem if you want to scale the picture. I give another solution with the possibility of scaling.

Comment: One small doubt : How do I write x_1, x_2, ..., x_5 instead of x?

Comment: @Altermundus: you are right that my solution doesn't allow the scaling, but I thought that the OP had in mind a fixed image with dimensions already given.

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino Yes it's possible but I always avoid the use of positioning, because  I think it's more easy to adjust and I discovered TikZ when `positioning` doesn't exist !! With positioning the distance depends of `node distance`and for the syntax, the only advantage of `positioning` is right or left are more explicit for some users.

Comment: The edited part is not working. What is this count?

Comment: @user1280282: `count` allows to count the items in the `foreach`, thus it is really helpful in this case. Which error do you receive?

Comment: @Altermundus: yes, I think each one has a different programming style. Since in general I build pictures for my documents that does not require any scaling, I use `positioning` quite a lot.

Comment: Use of \i doesn't match its definition ... node[right]{\footnotesize{$x_{\xi}$}} ;}

Comment: Probably you have an updated version of pgf. Update it and load the library `positioning` in your code (since in the edit you did in your question it is commented).